# How to use Fiddler and imacros with multi-threading

Tags: fiddler, imacros

I want to debug a site using imacros and Fiddler (I am open to another solutions that can log a traffic and autosave a log). Never done it before.

It is a 1 site that I will run using 5-10 simultaneous firefox profiles.

What I cannot understand is how will I differentiate which log correspond to which firefox profile since they run simultaneously.

> VERSION BUILD=11.5.498.2403;  Windows 10;  iMacros Browser + Firefox
>   iMacros 8.9.7; Firefox 49.0.2